# i want to print the value of "i" from 0 to 1000

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, charat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
/*how ican make String.fromCharCode(i)
```

i take value from 0 to 1000 so print out letter every time */

### JavaScript For Loop

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
/*String.fromCharCode(i) "i" print the letter only 1000 
and i want to print from 0 to 1000 */
text = String.fromCharCode(i)+ "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you're completely reassigning the value of `text` every iteration. Instead, *append* onto the previous value with `text += String...`

Comment: thanx very much it,s work now

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript For Loop</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  text += 'i' + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```